# why water is a proof of a life?

Tags: zoology, life

I read that NASA looks for water on Mars or other planets as a sign of a life.

I wonder why scientists look for water as proof of a life? isn't there any animal that drinks another liquid like alcohol or something?

Comment: duplicate: "An identical copy; a facsimile." please see the definition of the duplicate on http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duplicate it is not a duplicate...

Comment: A "duplicate" means the same or a very similar question has already been asked and has one or more sufficient answers. If there is something that has not been addressed to your satisfaction, feel free to [edit](http://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/9393/edit) your question to explain what further information you're looking for.

Comment: sorry, I shouldn't have fed the troll...

Comment: Water is not a proof of life. It is just indicating that life might be possible there.